# Windows Phone Whatsap Share Text

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, whatsapp

Is possible to share text to WhatsApp app in Windows Phone?
I found only way to run app. But how to share data like on Android or iOS?

```
 await Windows.System.Launcher.LaunchUriAsync(new Uri("whatsapp:"));
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As of now, there's no such way that you could share data with the `WhatsApp` application.

Reference: [Share content via whatsapp in wp8 apps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21146271/)

But you could still have a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25364225/show-viber-whatsup-in-windows-phone-8-1-share-contract), which talks about sharing data in multiple medias, if you're willing to try developing on `WP8.1`.